# How can rename Node of Tree view control on double click in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, node.js

I have need to rename node of the tree-view control on double click of node in asp.net c#.Since there is no double-click event in the asp.net tree view control so please any one can provide me some idea about how can create a custom double click event and how can rename tree-view node.

Answer (score 1):

You can use single click event to catch double click: just compare last click time with current time and if difference is less then double click period - it is definitely double click event. Something like:

```
DateTime LastClickTime = DateTime.MinValue;

void on_click()
{
    if (DateTime.Now - LastClickTime < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
        on_double_click();

    LastClickTime = DateTime.Now;     
}
```